# RhoHub : how to get local changes into RhoHub editor

Tags: git, rhodes, rhomobile

I'm trying out the RhoHub editor and Rhodes framework.  I'm trying to follow their tutorial and having some trouble seeing my local changes in the RhoHub editor.

I have setup my local git repository and added a local model,view,controller with the command 'rhodes model product name,brand,price,quantity,sku' and this creates the appropriate files.  Good!

I then issue the following git commands:

```
git add .
git commit -m "added new model"
git push origin master
```

Everything seems good as there are no errors displayed.

I then go to rhohub project page and click 'Launch Editor'.  None of my changes are displayed?  Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once in the editor, use the following steps to see your local changes:

1. Click "Actions" > "Commit"
2. In the third box on the left, you should see a "Remote Changes" section, with your local changes
3. Click "Reload App" to load the changes into the editor

Comment: ahh, it is starting to make sense.  the editor pulls from its local repository and must be synced with the master repository.  this way making changes in the editor is pretty much the same as making changes on a local computer.

Comment: Yep, it's the whole "distributed version control" idea, I suppose.